# JavaScript Short-Circuit Still Throws Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, undefined, short-circuit-evaluation

I'm working with some older code in AngularJs.  There's a variable `someVar1` that could possibly exist in the JS ether and if it does, I wanted to attach it to my scope like so:

```
$scope.someVar2 = someVar1 || 0;
```

But occasionally, when `someVar1` doesn't exist in the ether, I get this error:

*Error: someVar1 is not defined*

It points directly to the line and column of `someVar1` in the JS file.

Why is this happening?  I was under the impression that `someVar1 || 0` would check if `someVar1` was undefined, which is falsy, and set the `$scope.someVar2` to 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. Mainly because the someVar1 is in another file and I believe sometimes the file isn't even loaded and that's why it's undefined.  The question is mainly, why isn't the short-circuit catching the undefined?

Comment: @palaѕн I was able to simulate this and added gpouilloux's fix.  https://jsfiddle.net/ScubaShneve/o6cL4asg/

Comment: Ok, I have also linked a question as duplicate if you want to look into it.

Comment: It is very close, especially since the answer to this is one of the answers to the question that you linked.  The difference I see is that I'm asking more why the short-circuit isn't catching it since undefined is falsy.  The answer to my question explains that referencing the variable throws the error instead of undefined being checked in the short-circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have `someVar1` being potentially `undefined`, this variable must be declared first.

In your case, it is possible that the code in charge of defining `someVar1` is called after this script (or maybe never).

I'd suggest checking this in the first place.

As a hack, you could check if the variable is defined yourself by using `typeof`.

`typeof` will not throw a `ReferenceError` is the variable is not defined but instead will reply `undefined` if the variable is not defined or have `undefined` value.

For example, your code can look like this:

```js
$scope.someVar2 = typeof(someVar1) !== "undefined" ? someVar1 : 0;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined

Comment: can you add typeof(someVar1) === "undefined" somewhere in your answer and I'll accept it?